# DatepickerWidget in CreateView

Tags: django, jquery-ui-datepicker, django-class-based-views

In my model I have a Datefield. So I want to use a Datepicker. How to use the Django-Admin Datepicker?

I have found examples to do this in a Form, but I have only desined a model.
Is it possible to define this widget in my Model?

Comment: Does it have to be admin-datepicker or can you use any datepicker js plugin?

Comment: I use the datepicker form jquery-ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_form` method to override widget attribute:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['date_field'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
        return form
```

Comment: For django 1.10, get_form's form_class accepts a default None, so it can be skipped. [ref](https://github.com/django/django/blob/711123e1cdaf3b08c876c045d8d38decdc7a63d3/django/views/generic/edit.py#L30). Also, to completely override the widget altogether, instead of just updating the html class attribute, use `form.fields['field_name'].widget = SomeNewWidget`

Comment: i found this error get_form() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form_class'

Comment: i found this error get_form() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form_class'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full, modern solution based on the other answers:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['date_field', ...]

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(MyModelCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['date_field'].widget = AdminDateWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        return form
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to create a modelform,
in that form file import the admin datepicker widget

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
```

and define the widgets for that field using attrs=AdminDateWidget

and in template put {{ form.media }} to get include that widget javascript and css files in html