# Django 1.11 CreateView adding datepicker for datefields

Tags: django, datepicker

So I am trying to change my form's model Datefield output to the Datepicker similar to [DatepickerWidget in CreateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405895/datepickerwidget-in-createview)

The forms are generated using a html template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.error }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{field.label_tag}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the Views with what I tried:

```
class newenv_form(generic.CreateView):
    model = Environment
    fields =['name', 'description', 'creation_date', 'status','status_update_date']
    template_name = 'catalogue/new_env.html'

    #Does not work
    def get_form(self, form):
        form = super(newenv_form, self)
        form.fields['creation_date','status_update_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})
        return form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked but it is a dropdown datepicker that is limited in choices

```
def get_form(self):
        '''add date picker in forms'''
        from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
        form = super(EnvironmentCreateView, self).get_form()
        form.fields['creation_date'].widget = SelectDateWidget()
        return form
```

Note that I remove form_class which was causing problems

**UPDATE:** On Django 3.1, you can find `SelectDateWidget` within `django.forms.widgets`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the following line in the method `get_form`:

```
form = super(newenv_form, self)
```

to:

```
form = super(newenv_form, self).get_form(form)
```

And please follow the conventions and use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for class names in python.
You could call this class `EnvironmentCreateView`. Further generic view classes could be called for example `EnvironmentListView`, `EnvironmentDetailView`, `EnvironmentUpdateView`, `EnvironmentDeleteView`.
 Using the same pattern for all your model classes will produce comprehensible code.

EDIT (2017-10-24):

Regarding your comment here is a further explanation. Although it is hard to give a correct remote diagnosis, I'd suggest the following changes:

```
class EnvironmentCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    # class attributes ...
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(EnvironmentCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        # further code ...
```

The essential changes are in bold. The class name is changed to meet the conventions. Also the parameter `form` is changed to `form_class` to meet the convetions, too. I emphasise conventions in particular, because it makes the code very comprehensible to other people familiar with the framework.
The important change is that `form_class` has the initial value `None`.
That should solve the problem with the error.
In the body of the method you call the parent method with `super` and write after that your custom code.

Please check the documentation for [`generic.CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview). It inherits, among others, from [`generic.FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin). That is the class with the method `get_form`.

Comment: not sure why but I am getting an type error `get_form() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'`